# Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px' with bootstrap 4 alpha 6

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, incompatibletypeerror

I am trying to implement a bootstrap 4 template (I use bootstrap 4 alpha 6) and see such an error:

```
Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'.
```

in line

```
$input-height: (($font-size-base * $input-btn-line-height) + ($input-btn-padding-y * 2)) !default;
```

Did somebody experience similar issue?
Thanks!

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bootstrap moved from pixels (px) in version 3 to rem in version 4.

In `resources/assets/sass/_variables.scss` replace:

`$font-size-base: 14px;` with  `$font-size-base: 1rem;`

In general, Bootstrap 4 uses 'rem' instead of 'px'. For reference, look at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17070

Comment: 14px is equal to .875rem, if root font size is 16px

Comment: Remember to restart server if you are upgrading from bootstrap 3, changing gems or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

This happens, as Laravel 5.4 by default uses a *variables.scss* compatible with the **3.3.X** version of Bootstrap.

For Bootstrap 4, just remove the import of the 3.3.X variables file in

*resouces/assets/sass/app.scss*

and replace

```
// Variables
@import "variables";
```

with

```
// Variables
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think a better solution would be to edit the contents of ``resources/assets/sass/_variables.scss`` rather than importing (the already imported) ``node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss`` file.

Answer (score 0):

The `$font-size-base` variable is already `1rem` in the latest Bootstrap 4.1.3.

The problem is definitely with the `$font-size-base` variable though.

Since Bootstrap uses `rem` as unit of measurement globally you can just set the `$font-size-base` to `1` (removing the `rem` part) and that allows you to compile your SASS without problems. It seems to be working fine as well since the calculations using `$font-size-base` specify `rem` eventually.

I might be wrong but this is what worked for me, hopefully it will help someone else.

This way you can import your custom variables without problems.